# Is there any way to restrict from access certain LookML view file who have develop permission?

Tags: permissions, reporting, business-intelligence, looker

Is there any way to restrict editing certain view files to those users who has develop permission?

[image]

Basically what I want to do is. I have a lookML view files in two folders base and client. everyone who has develop permission can access both folders and do modification and deletion on them but I want to restrict to modification and deletion from the one of the folder (base folder) and not from another(client folder). The only see_lookml permission to the base folder but see_lookml and develop both permissions to the client folder.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this recently, and found that the only way to create this kind of permission silo in Looker is to segment the developers by Model access. It is clunky and doesn't solve your problem, but as it stands today if the users have access to the Model they have access to all the .View files below.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)